# How to upload files using Vaadin and angular2

Tags: angular, vaadin

I want to use the vaalin component to upload files in my angular app.

```
 <vaadin-upload max-files="3" accept="image/*" max-file-size="1000000">
        <div class="drop-label">
          <iron-icon icon="file-upload"></iron-icon>
          Accepts up to 8 image files, up to 1 MB each
        </div>
 </vaadin-upload>
```

How do I use this to upload files to a firebase storage?

Comment: Hello @Ericel. Please add come code snippets to this question. It's hard to answer anything helpful to "How do I use this to upload files to a firebase storage?" :)

Add your Angular2 code related to uploading functionality.

Comment: Have you tried this component? https://github.com/samiheikki/firebase-upload/ it wraps vaadin-upload